# Insert dynamic Column to HBase thru Pig Latin

Tags: hbase, apache-pig

I am writing to ask for how to insert dynamic columns to HBase thru Pig Latin. The case is that my pig script will generate the following relation:
(key, date, value)
(key, date, value)
(key, date, value)

And I wanna save them to my HBase. Obviously, key is the row key, but I wanna date could be a column defined in my columnFamily.

I know that HBaseStorage can be used to save data, like below. But the issue is that I cannot specify **** because it's designed to be dynamic. How can I deal with this scenario? Thanks in advance!

STORE relation INTO 'hbase://user' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('cf:{****}');

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there's no built in pig functionality that will let you do that. However you can write a [customized STORE user-defined-function](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/udf.html#load-store-functions) to handle your case. You can even start with the [HBaseStorage implementation](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pig/trunk/src/org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop/hbase/HBaseStorage.java) as a baseline